# PHP: define functions with variable names

Tags: php

I have an array of strings and I want to define functions with names being these strings. Is there a way to do that in PHP?

```
$a = array("xxx", "yyy", "zzz");
```

How do I programmatically define `xxx()`, `yyy()`, and `zzz()`?

Many thanks

Comment: lets say you did define these strings as functions, what will you do with them?

Comment: They're hooks in a CMS. I want my plugin to do the exact same thing on every hook.

Comment: Would anonymous functions be more useful to you? http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php.

Comment: that means you just want to declare them as function without a definition (already defined in this case). If that is the case, you dont need to declare them. Just call them be appending () with each string and possible parameters.

Comment: @SavageGarden No, I want to define them, not call them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a variable to define a PHP function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213825/use-a-variable-to-define-a-php-function)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you really had to you could declare the function within an [`eval`](http://php.net/eval) block:

```
foreach ($a as $functionname)
eval('
        function '.$functionname.' () {
            print 123;
        }
');
```

But that incurs some extra parsing time speed penalty over just declaring the functions in a file.

Comment: Since it's for a strictly-development-only helper module, performance's not an issue, so I guess I'll use this approach. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I'll end up generating my PHP file from another PHP script, that will be cleaner. And it's so meta! :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't, it's not possible.

With a magic method trick you can achieve this on an instance object (so $obj->xxx() works, see: [__call](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods)) but you cannot create a global function based on a variable name.

Note: I am aware that you can $var(), but that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have more info on this magic method trick?

Comment: I'm not sure this would work in my case (hooks definition in a CMS). Will try it though, thanks.

Comment: @julien_c Let me guess! You probably asked this question while you were working with Drupal update hooks? It's a mess. How did you solve it finally?

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array("xxx", "yyy", "zzz");

foreach($a as $functionname){
$code = <<< end
function $functionname(){
//your logic here for each function
}
end;
eval($code);
}
```

However please not that Eval is not advisable to be used, you should find some other approach.