# Use Variable as Function Name in PHP

Tags: php, function, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use a variable to define a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213825/use-a-variable-to-define-a-php-function)

Is there a way of using a variable as a function name.

For example i have a variable

```
$varibaleA;
```

and I want to create a function i.e.

```
function $variableA() {
}
```

so this function can be called later in the script. Does anyone know if this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: why ever you think this is a good idea, theirs probably a better solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use a variable to define a PHP function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213825/use-a-variable-to-define-a-php-function) or [PHP: define functions with variable names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337883/php-define-functions-with-variable-names)

Comment: Not a duplicate. That one asks to define a function using *Dynamic* names - not just with a variable.

Comment: BY any chance, do you want to create a dynamic function

Comment: As said by @mario, : `$functionToCall = 'show__personalizer_'.$_GET['page'];`, then `$functionToCall()`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Declaring a function with a variable but arbitrary name like this is not possible without getting your hands dirty with `eval()` or `include()`.

I *think* based on what you're trying to do, you'll want to store an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in that variable instead (use [`create_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) if you're not on PHP 5.3+):

```
$variableA = function() {
    // Do stuff
};
```

You can still call it as you would any [variable function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), like so:

```
$variableA();
```

Comment: Save yourself the nuisance. Note the `;` after the `}`.

Answer (score 18):

```
$x = 'file_get_contents';
$html = $x('http://google.com');
```

is functionally equivalent to doing

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://google.com');
```

They're called [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), and generally should be avoided as they're too far removed from variable variables.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this:

```
$foo = function() {
    //..
};
```

and then:

```
$foo();
```

works in PHP 5.3+