# Make for loop function that run another function

Tags: php

Is possible to make for loop function for php, that works like this

```
function hit(){

}

function forLoop($function, $times) {

for($x = 0; $x < $times; $x++) {
    $function;
}

$this->forLoop($function, 5);
```

Comment: For sure! Just try it out. (Typo 1: forgot 1 closing curly bracket for the `forLoop` function Typo 2: parentheses for the function call: `$function();`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Variable as Function Name in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466473/use-variable-as-function-name-in-php)

Comment: Could I do $this->forLoop($this->getScore, 5);

Comment: If your code is in a class context e.g. class declaration and `$this->getScore` Is holding a name for a function sure why not?

Comment: can I do $this->getScore($something), 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) function:

```
function hit(){
    echo "hello !";
}

function forLoop($function, $times) {

    for($x = 0; $x < $times; $x++) {
        call_user_func($function);
    }
}

forLoop('hit', 5);
```

Comment: You also can simply write: `$function();`

Comment: for ($hole = 0; $hole < 18; $hole++) {
                    $function;
                }                    public function generateCourse($course, $type) {
        $this->runFunction($this->generateHole($hole), $type);
    }