# How to call the function / method in the controller that received from the dropdown list in the views

Tags: php, codeigniter

From the view I passed the value i.e test(); to the controller

```
<select name="FUNCT_NAME">
    <option value="test();">
</select>
```

I loaded the concern helper already in which the concerned function is defined i.e.

```
if ( ! function_exists('test')){
   function test()
   {
      echo "Got here";
   }
}
```

Now in the concerned controller I received it as,

```
 $func_name   = $this->input->post('FUNCT_NAME'); //test();
    /*
      it gives me the name of the function i.e test();, not call that 
      function i.e. test(); declared in helper. Desired output Got here
   */
    print_r($func_name);
```

Now I want to call the test(); in the helper which is not calling. Kindly share the key if any.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call function name with () scopes. For example :

```php
$func_name = $_GET['func'];
function test(){
    echo 'aaaa';
}

echo $func_name();
```

Additioanlly, for more examples you can see here: [Use Variable as Function Name in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466473/use-variable-as-function-name-in-php)