# Can anonymous functions be called by the variable value?

Tags: php, arrays, function, for-loop, anonymous-function

I have a loop that iterates through values in an array.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tables); $i++) {
    $tables[$i]['form'] = function() {
    // function stuff
    };
}
```

How can I now call my functions using the values from the array as the function names?

Comment: What do you want the function to do?

Comment: Yes, via `$tables[$i]['form']();`

Comment: The function generates HTML for a plugin options page that sits in the Wordpress admin area. There are a number of tabs that allow users to view, edit and delete records in database tables. Each function represents the view/edit/delete options for a different table. Since users can add or delete their own tables, there needs to be a way of dynamically generating these pages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create functions in a loop with names from elements in an array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127351/create-functions-in-a-loop-with-names-from-elements-in-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can call it directly:

```
    $tables[1]['form']();
```

Or with `call_user_func`:

```
   call_user_func($tables[$i]['form']);
```

Parameters to your function are passes as additional parameters to the `call_user_func()` for example:

```
 $tables[1]['form'] = function($a){echo $a;};
 call_user_func($tables[1]['form'], 'booo');
 //would echo out 'booo'
```