# PHP variable function

Tags: php, function, variables

Let's pretend this is happening inside of a class method (pure example):

```
public function runEvent($funcName, $params)
{
 $funcName($this, $params);
}

//somewhere else
function myFunc($anBOject, $paramsHere, $somethingElse = NULL)
{
 //do stuff
}

$SomeClassObj->runEvent('myFunc', array('dog', 'cat'));
```

Can I assume PHP will execute myFunc with the first parameter being $this, second being $params, and then NULL as the 3rd param (by default)?

This question is more just for understanding how PHP deals with variable functions. Im not actually having any issues in a certain project.

Thanks!

Comment: "Can I assume" -- can you just check it yourself? It would take couple of minutes

Comment: Thought it would also be a good reference for anyone in the future who was thinking the same thing.

Comment: if checking yourself takes less than asking a question - there is no reason to bother yourself and community, imho

Comment: you should also make sure you check the function exists before calling it and protect the script from injected code else you could have problems later on...

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yup, this was just an example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use a variable to define a PHP function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213825/use-a-variable-to-define-a-php-function). @Kovo That's sloppy logic. If that were true you should get to work duplicating the php.net manual as stackoverflow questions.

Comment: @MikeB it seems that there is already almost every PHP manual page here at SO.... no need to duplicate, solution is to [query the database](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
$funcName($this, $params);
```

is called exactly the same way as

```
myFunc($this, $params);
```

The first parameter is `$this`, the second `$params`, there's no third.

To call functions with a variable number of arguments, use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array).

Comment: @zerkms figured it out before, and now future devs will be able to reference this post. Goal accomplished.

Comment: @Kovo: there are already a bunch of similar questions here. Goal has been accomplished long ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213825/use-a-variable-to-define-a-php-function