# php calling a function using a string

Tags: php

i have below a function called test thats being called, and just echos "test" keeping it simple, for this question.

```
test();

function test() {
    echo "do something";
}
```

However i want to try and make the function dynamic if thats the right choice of words.

I have a list of records in a database, and based on each record, i may want a different function to process that record, the idea then is to have a field in the database which would be function_name, i then use that field to some how call that function.

Like this

```
test();

$function_name = "test";
function $function_name() {
    echo "do something here";
}
```

the only way i can think to get around this is to use switch/case but that is going to cause me other issues down the line.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7213825/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1005857/ - http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php which are inside those Q's & A's. One of those is probably a duplicate of.

Comment: *There's always a method to one's madness* - @JohnConde

Comment: @ John Conde, as explained i have a database with a lot of records, and each record is related to a url and to data mine it. I then have different functions to deal with the different websites im wanting to mine, so using a job server i send the url and function name to process the html to the worker.

Comment: Often times that madness is called an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

The function has to be defined with a specific name but you can call it using a variable that contains its name like so :-

```
<?php
function name() {
    echo "name";
}

$func_name = 'name';

// its always a good idea to check that function 
// actually exists before calling it.
if (function_exists($func_name)) {
    $func_name();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use closures for this:

```
<?php

$funcName = 'test';

$$funcName = function ()
{
    echo 'Do something';
};

$test(); // 'Do something'
$$funcName(); // 'Do something'
```

Comment: hi, how does this differ to RiggsFolly's answer?

Comment: @Skydiver1977 the main difference is that the function. Is being initialised with a dynamic name, not just being called that way. After that, they both are pretty much the same  just an alternative